# How to get content of Div using C#?

Tags: c#

```
<div dir="ltr">
  <div>1 Tom</div>
  <div>2 Anna</div>
  <div>3 Alex</div>
  <div>4 Jax<br /></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="gmail_quote">
  <div class="gmail_attr">
  .......Somethings  
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get all content inside tag `<div dir="ltr">` like this :

1 Tom 2 Anna ...

Comment: Well, you can use some built-in objects, such as `XDocument`. Do some research and try to solve the task on your own. Come back with specific problem :)

Comment: you need `javascript` to take the value correctly, else u need to use the `server control` to get it

Comment: What is the context? What is generating the HTML? How are you loading it into your C# program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NuGet called called https://html-agility-pack.net/ which is pretty convenient to use:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);

var query = $"div[@dir='ltr']";
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
string content = node.InnerHtml;
```